# Taking Back-Up of WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a question regarding WordPress.

I am new to web development (3 months) and at present I am working on a project and moving to stage 2 of the project. Before starting stage 2, I want to take the back up of what I have done so far.

My question is, is it enough to take the back up of folders wp-admin, wp-content & wp-includes.

And in case I screw up the stage 2, is it enough to restore the above 3 folders back, and will the WordPress application work the way it worked for stage 1 ?

Please throw some light on it.

thanks a bunch.

Isaac

Comment: why not just the entire site?

Comment: The only things you need to backup are the `wp-content` folder and your `wp-config.php` file. And your database of course :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I am NOT changing the theme, why should I take the back up of the database ? Is it a must ?

Comment: You MUST do a database backup.  WP stores user info, settings, page/post info, etc... in the database, not just theme info.  If you lose your database you'll basically lose your site.  The most complete and easiest back solution is Backup Buddy by iThemes.  You can find it here: http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/